# Matplotlib subplot axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Any help with the issue is appreciated. I am trying to make subplots using matplotlib and the code I wrote is as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

Fig, Axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
plt.tight_layout()
for i in range(0, NoOfVehicles):
  Axes[i].set_aspect(1)
  Axes[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.NullFormatter())
  Axes[i].yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.NullFormatter()
```

Now how do I plot something in first plot and then something else in the second.

I want to do

```
nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes(GPlot[0].G, GPlot[0].Position, node_size=100, node_color=GPlot[0].Color)
```

in the first plot and

```
nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes(GPlot[1].G, GPlot[1].Position, node_size=100, node_color=GPlot[1].Color)
```

in the second.

In summary, this is what I want to do : I want the first set of nodes to come in subplot(1,2,1) and the second in subplot(1,2,2). But both come in the same plot (1,2,2).

GPlot is just a list that contains 2 objects of a class GraphPlot

```
class GraphForPlot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.G = nx.Graph()
        self.Components = []
        self.ActiveStatus = {}
        self.Nodes = []
        self.Position = {}
        self.Color = []
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  What do you expect the code to do and what is it doing?

Comment: I want the first set of nodes to come in subplot(1,2,1) and the second in subplot(1,2,2). But both come in the same plot (1,2,2)

Comment: What is `GPlot`?  You should edit your question to include your previous comment, as well as what `GPlot` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `netwkorkx` which axes to draw into, if you do not, it will draw into the currently active axis (what ever `plt.gca()` returns ([doc](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkxhttp://)).

```
nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes(..., ax=Axes[0])
nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes(..., ax=Axes[1])
```

As a side note, you should not use camel case for instance variables ([pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)), it can lean to clashes with class names (in this case `matplotlib.axes.Axes`).

Comment: I get the following error if I do that:
    ValueError: Argument must be an image, collection, or ContourSet in this Axes

Comment: Okay it works if I do:
ax=plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
But I don't know why it does not work if I do it the way you mentioned

Comment: what is the result `type(Axes[0])`?

Comment: <class 'matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot'>

Comment: I don't understand the source of that error.  If your workaround does not work sufficiently, I would post another question with a complete working example that generates that error.